# Error handling with jquery v3 and load event

Tags: jquery

The jquery v2~ supports load function:

```
$(selector).load(function () {}).error(function(){});
```

The jquery v3~ doesn't support load function and we need to use the on function:

```
$(selector).on('load', function () {});
```

How can I handle errors with the on function?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/).

Comment: @Bla... This post is only about silent errors in async `ready` states. That is not the question here. Your case is very special. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure, jQuery 3 still supports `.load()` to load content. Only the event listener creation and trigger needs to use `.on()` and `.trigger()`.

```
// jQuery 2
$("selector").load(function() {
    console.log("I'm loaded!");
});
$("selector").load();

// jQuery 2 + jQuery 3
$("selector").on("load", function() {
    console.log("I'm loaded!");
});
$("selector").trigger("load");
```

The error handling is the same. `.error()` is deprected, use `on` again:

```
// jQuery 2 + jQuery 3
$("selector").on("load", function() {
    console.log("I'm loaded!");
}).on("error", function() {
    console.log("I'm having errors!");
});
$("selector").trigger("error");
```

Or combine both event listeners in a single `.on()`:

```
// jQuery 2 + jQuery 3
$("selector").on({
    load: function() {
        console.log("I'm loaded!");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("I'm having errors!");
    }
});
$("selector").trigger("load");
$("selector").trigger("error");
```